# how to set dynamical range until empty cell hit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This might be easy for many but I need to solve an issue which is following;

I have a spread sheet that will always be from Columns D to D but the range of the amount of rows can vary. I want to Select all cells in ranges from D4 until the first blank cell in column D, so if the data ends at row 8 it will stop selecting the rows at cell D8.

I tried to make it dynamical but currently i could only limit my formel to D10.

My initial formal is following and D8 values should be dynamic:

```
=IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Completion delayed")>0;"Completion delayed";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Start delayed")>0;"Start delayed";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"In progress")>0;"In progress";IF(
  AND(COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Not started")>0;COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Done")>0);"In progress";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Not started")>0;"Not started";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Done")>0;"Done";"N/A"
))))))
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Why not just `D:D` and let it ride. Or do you have more data happening beneath the first blank row in D?

Comment: exactly. from d4 to d10 or d11 or d12 etc (the number will vary) there are data. Then there will be one blank cell and i will use the same formular after this blank cell (for example d13) to next blank cell, which means i will use the similar formula which defines a range from selected cell to next empty cell

Comment: Needs sample data and expected results.

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: sadly no, i need formula

Comment: What determines how many rows should be used?  When you know that, you can use [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) to create a range to look at, e.g. `OFFSET($D$1,3,0,5,1)` will be the same as `$D$4:$D$8'

Comment: there is no determination logic for the row amounts. it will start at d4 thats sure but how many will be added is not known so it should be dynamical

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as an array formula, entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D"&MAX((D:D<>"")*(ROW(D:D)))),"Abort")>0,"Abort","")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can i add this to my following formula which i edited in my question?